# Why did TypeScript not create immutable types to address array covariance & prevent variables from being indirectly assigned values of the wrong type?

Tags: typescript, casting

I have constructed the following code, which compiles without any warnings or errors:

```js
const x: number[] = [1,2,3];
const y: any[] = x;

y[0] = "hello";
y[1] = x;

const x0: number = x[0];
const x1: number = x[1];

console.log(typeof x0);
console.log(typeof x1);
console.log(x as any === x1 as any);
```

But even though I've declared `x0` and `x1` to be numbers without error and without an explicit cast, `typeof` reveals that they're *not* numbers at all, and by casting `x` and `x1` to `any`, we can see that they're the same object, even though they have different and incompatible declared types! (Indeed, `x === x` produces "error TS2367: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'number' and 'number[]' have no overlap.")

It seems to me that upcasting to `any[]` isn't safe and shouldn't be allowed. This could be solved by introducing immutable types, since upcasting to `immutable any[]` would be safe since it's always safe to *read* an array as if one doesn't know the type of its contents. Has such a fix ever been proposed?

I AM **NOT** ASKING WHY ARRAYS ARE COVARIANT. I AM ASKING IF OR WHY IMMUTABLE TYPES WERE NOT CONSIDERED IN ORDER TO PREVENT BAD VALUES GETTING ASSIGNED TO AN ARRAY.

Comment: @E_net4 Not really. Certainly it's related, and interesting reading, but it doesn't answer the question "has [introducing immutable types as] a fix [for covariance] ever been proposed?"

Comment: It does answer the question "Did I break typescript", and addresses directly everything in your question except for *possibly* the very last bit "has such a fix ever been proposed" (although it does answer "even if proposed they wouldn't do it to fix the issue you're talking about") but if that is your question, it should probably be front and center of the question.

Comment: The all caps yelling is really not helping anyone here.

Comment: @jcalz There is only one question mark in my post. I would have thought it was obvious that that was the question. I thought I would give it a humorous title, but apparently that gets you ostracized, so I have replaced it with a long boring title instead.

Comment: I find it best to assume that people are interacting in good faith. I can assure you that I've read both this and the other post, and writing in all caps and trying to scold others into changing things is ineffective at best.  At this point, since the question is closed, the onus is on you to explain *why* the other question and its answer doesn't address it, not just declare it.  I'm willing to continue to engage if the tone becomes more civil.  I have not downvoted and rarely downvote (indeed I upvoted this question). But closing questions as duplicates is not "ostracizing".

Comment: @tadman I put it in all caps because apparently nobody read the part of the post that wasn't in all caps.

Comment: Regardless, it makes it look like you're here to start a fight. This might be worth discussing in a TypeScript forum, as here it's hard to answer concisely.

Comment: Asking why something was or wasn't designed in some way is considered opinion-based and thus off-topic.